# Выборка и удаление таблиц по маске

Tags: sql, sql-server

В базе данных есть таблицы с именами вида `shablon_4YVC`, `shablon_6HGFT`, `shablon_9GGNF` и т.д.

Как сделать DROP всех таких таблиц, не перечисляя их поименно?
Нужно что-то типа:

```
DROP TABLE LIKE 'shablon_%'
```

Answer (score 2):

В SQL Server есть такая недокументированная процедура:

```
   exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'drop table ?', 
        @whereand = 'and o.name like ''%pattern%'' and xtype=''U'''
```

Однако могут помешать внешние ключи, как, впрочем, и при любом другом способе.
Так что сначала нужно дропнуть ссылочные ограничения, а потом таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали какую СУБД Вы используете, поэтому приведу пример для MS SQLServer.

Для начала надо получить список таблиц:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    sys.obejcts
WHERE
    name LIKE '%pattern%'
    AND type = 'U' --пользовательская таблица
```

Затем перебираете все и для каждого генерируете строчку с нужной инструкцией. После чего выполняете эту строку как скрипт. В SQLServer'е для этого можно сделать `EXEC('...')`, но лучше воспользоваться [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001.aspx).

Только будьте предельно внимательны при подобных операциях, дабы не грохнуть лишнего.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: @mixerden, судя по MSDN, sp_executesql есть и в 2005-м, так что пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так:

```
USE MyTable

SELECT

CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', name) AS Result_Command -- Объединил текст и имя таблицы

FROM sys.objects

WHERE name LIKE '%old' -- выбираю таблицы у которых имя оканчивается на "old"

and type = 'U' -- выбираю только пользовательские таблицы

ORDER BY name -- сортирую результат по именам таблиц для красоты
```

В результате получаем строки типа `DROP TABLE table1_old`

Копируем их в новое окно запроса в начале поставив `USE MyTable`.

Получим что то вроде:

```
USE MyTable

DROP TABLE table1_old

DROP TABLE table2_old

DROP TABLE table999_old
```

Ну и запускаем скрипт